# How would I transfer 5-letter words into a new text file?

Tags: java, text

Let's say I have a txt file that has the whole dictionary in it. how would I make this code be able to transer only 5-letter words into a new created txt file?

```
 import java.io.*;
 public class wordwebster {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int five = 0;
    File directory = new File(".");
    String webster = directory.getCanonicalPath() + File.separator+ "webster.txt";
    String fiveLetterWords = directory.getCanonicalPath()+ File.separator +"fiveLetterWords.txt";

    File fin = new File(webster);
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(fin);
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));

    FileWriter fileStream = new FileWriter(fiveLetterWords,true);
    BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(fileStream);

    String line = null;
    while ((line = input.readLine())!= null){
        output.write(line);
        output.newLine();

    }
    input.close();

    output.close();
}
}
```

EDIT:

As asked, let's say the input file (webster.txt) contain the words

```
Sentence
Frequent 
Hello 
Send 
Variety 
False
```

I would need only five letter words be extracted (Hello and False) and be put into a new file (fiveLetterWords.txt).

Comment: How does your input file contains words inside it? If each line contains only one word, you can filter words in each line else you may have to split the words in whole line. Can you add some sample lines from your input file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to allow only words whose length is exactly five, you can just put an if condition to check before writing into file. Modify your while loop to this,

```
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.trim().length() == 5) {
        output.write(line);
        output.newLine();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: This has helped alot, however, I have changed the if line to only line.length since it would output the rest of the words but other than that thank you!

Comment: Pleased to help :)